# Why does pathlib.Path("C:") resolve to the working directory on Windows?

Tags: python, pathlib

Using Python 3.6 on Windows 7 x64, the path `"C:"` seems identical to an empty path for `Path.resolve()`:

'Empty' paths are 'current working directory' `cwd()`:

```
>>> from pathlib import Path
>>> Path().resolve()
WindowsPath('C:/Users/me')
>>> Path(r"").resolve()
WindowsPath('C:/Users/me')
>>> Path.cwd().resolve()
WindowsPath('C:/Users/me')
```

A single letter is interpreted as a folder name:

```
>>> Path(r"C").resolve()
WindowsPath('C:/Users/me/C')
```

A full blown drive-letter + colon + backslash points to the drive root as expected:

```
>>>> Path(r"C:\").resolve()
WindowsPath('C:/')
```

But forgetting the backslash points back to the current work directory?

```
>>>> Path(r"C:").resolve()
WindowsPath('C:/Users/me/C')
```

I would expect it to either treat the colon (without a backslash) as a regular character (it does so for `Path("te:st")`), or either ignore it (`"C"`), or treat the path as the drive root (`"C:\"`).  But instead it seems to ignore the C altogether.

For other drive letters (`"A:"`, `"X:"`, ...), resolve either hangs indefinitely (not nice!) or asks me to insert a disk into the drive (which indicates that it's not completely ignoring the drive letter either).

Comment: Probably the same reason (if I recall correctly - haven't used Windows in a *long* time) - that `cd C:` when you're in a directory doesn't change your path if it's on the same drive. eg: Windows is resolving it to a no-op of your cwd.

Comment: `C:` isn't a path. It's a drive letter *without* a path

Comment: @JonClements in Powershell cd-ing to a folder on another drive *does* change the path. `C:` isn't a path though

Comment: Well, depends tecnically what one calls a path (we could argue whether it's a drive letter or a partial path that doesn't have anything more than a driver letter etc...) or not - it happens to be something that resolves to the cwd when on the same drive...

Comment: @JonClements no it doesn't. The Windows API works the same way always. *Shells* and libraries may call different API functions though. A single letter C *is* a relative path to a local folder called `C`. The same as `Path(r"Cee")`. `Path(r"C:").resolve()` though seems to act like a `cd c:` which takes you to the current folder *in that drive*. If the computer has only one drive and the project is on that drive, one may assume that ``Path(r"C:").resolve()` acted as if it where a whitespace, when in fact, it simply remains on the current drive

Comment: @florisla Is your project stored on the C: drive perhaps? In this case a `cd c:` would leave you in the same drive. That would explain why `Path(r"A:").resolve()` tries to open the floppy drive and `Path(r"X:").resolve()` tries to find a mapped network drive

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos What you've said is what I was (thought I was anyway) saying... We've obviously misunderstood in our interpretations :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It does not.

At least not in the sense that `pathlib.Path("C:")` resolves to *the* working directory on Windows:

```
C:\Users\bersbers>d:

D:\>python
Python 3.8.1 (tags/v3.8.1:1b293b6, Dec 18 2019, 23:11:46) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from pathlib import Path
>>> Path.cwd().resolve()
WindowsPath('D:/')
>>> Path(r"C:").resolve()
WindowsPath('C:/Users/bersbers')
>>>
```

As you can see, `C:` resolves the last active directory *on the C: drive*, which is completely in line with how Windows uses `C:` vs. `C:\`:

```
D:\>dir C:\
 Volume in drive C is Windows
 Volume Serial Number is 1234-ABCD

 Directory of C:\

01/17/2020  10:34 AM    <DIR>          Program Files
01/18/2020  12:11 AM    <DIR>          Program Files (x86)
...
```

Compare that to this:

```
D:\>dir C:
 Volume in drive C is Windows
 Volume Serial Number is 1234-ABCD

 Directory of C:\Users\bersbers

01/20/2020  11:19 AM    <DIR>          .
01/20/2020  11:19 AM    <DIR>          ..
08/23/2018  10:45 AM    <DIR>          .cache
11/27/2019  11:26 PM             1,024 .rnd
...
```

This also applies to file paths:

```
D:\>copy C:\.rnd %TEMP%
The system cannot find the file specified.

D:\>copy C:.rnd %TEMP%
        1 file(s) copied.
```

And similarly:

```
C:\Users\bersbers>D:

D:\>cd C:
C:\Users\bersbers

D:\>C:

C:\Users\bersbers>
```

versus

```
C:\Users\bersbers>D:

D:\>cd C:\

D:\>C:

C:\>
```

So in summary, `Path("C:").resolve()` behaves exactly as you would expect it to, based on long-established Windows behavior.