# how to make the script to start running from the top folder on windows

Tags: python, size, disk

The location of this script is on D:
The script works for drives other than D:
On D: the script does not start from the top folder 
It starts from the script working directory  
How to make it start from the root?

```
  def folder_usage_one(folder):
        from pathlib import Path
        root = Path(folder)
        return (sum(f.stat().st_size 
                for f in root.glob('**/*') if f.is_file()))
```

Comment: Do you give the absolute path to the folder when you call folder_usage_one ?

Comment: @MathieuRollet I give the drive letters as an argument. Works with G:, F:, but does not work when I give D:.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using "D:\" for referencing the root of the D drive instead of "D:"

More details on this similar Q&A : [Why does pathlib.Path("C:") resolve to the working directory on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48810950/why-does-pathlib-pathc-resolve-to-the-working-directory-on-windows)